# Quarterly time conversion in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a columnm, which needs to when being converted to a quarterly value, since it does not fill the whole quarter up (i.e. It has has 2 out of 3 month of data), I want this column to collapse to a NULL value.

Consider the following:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter': [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                  'Month': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'Data': [0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})
```

Quarter 2, contains only 2 out of 3 months. However, it could also only contain 1 month to trigger the same condition.

How do I roll this up to look like this after aggregating down to a quarterly value?

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter': [0, 1, 2],
                  'Month': [0, 3, 5],
                  'Data': [0, 30, np.nan]})
```

Comment: Why doesn't quarter 0 also become NaN?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why would it? The `data` column is the column being acted upon.

Comment: We mean , the Quarter 0 only have one value , why in your dataframe b , Data , it showing 0 rather than NaN